# nullpointer exception when calling constructors

Tags: java

i keep getting a nullpointer execption whenever i try to call any of my constructor

```
public class Poly{

private static class Pair{

int coeff;
int exponent;

}

int count=1;

private Pair[] poly =new Pair[count];

public Poly(){

    poly = new Pair[count];
    poly[count-1].coeff=0;
    poly[count-1].exponent=0;
    count++;
}
public Poly(int coeff1, int exp){

    poly = new Pair[count];
    //poly.add(new Poly(coeff1, exp));
    poly[count-1].coeff=coeff1;
    poly[count-1].exponent=exp;
    count++;
}

private Poly (int exp) {

       poly = new Pair[exp+1];
       poly[0].exponent = exp;
    }





public String toString(){

    String str ="";
    for(int i=0; i<=count; i++){
        str+= poly[i].coeff +"x^" +poly[i].exponent;
    }
    return str;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Poly p =new Poly(5, 3);
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
poly = new Pair[count];
```

never calls the constructor, and so the next line

```
poly[count-1].coeff=0;
```

...fails with an NPE.

All the first line has done is create an array of `null` references, you haven't created any `Pair` objects. To actually create the `Pair` objects, you have to do that:

```
poly = new Pair[count];                    // Not calling the constructor
for (int i = 0; i < poly.length; ++i) {
    poly[i] = new Pair(/*...args...*/);    // Calling the constructor
}
poly[count-1].coeff=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to just instantiate the array itself. You have to instantiate the elements of your arrays too

```
public Poly(){

    poly = new Pair[count];
    poly[count-1] = new Pair(/*params*/);
    poly[count-1].coeff=0;
    poly[count-1].exponent=0;
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new array of objects they default to null so

```
Pair poly = new Pair[10];
poly[0] == null // true
poly[9] == null // true
```

You need to initialize your array

```
public Poly(){

    poly = new Pair[count];
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++) 
                poly[i] = new Pair();
    poly[count-1].coeff=0;
    poly[count-1].exponent=0;
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create an array-object with the size of count elements.

Every single element within the array is null, so

```
poly[count-1].coeff=0;
```

will thow a NullPointer.

You will have to create Pairs in you Poly sontructor:

```
for(int i =0;i<count;i++){
    poly[i] = new Pair();
}
```